# What is the use of Spring Framework Actually?

Tags: java, spring

Actually i have a big doubt before getting into Spring Framework, without knowing the correct reason i can't move further, i mean i can't learn blindly.

Let have a example having one class and we are going to access the variables.

```
public class Example {
  String name;

  Example() {
    this.name="Hello World"; 
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Example object=new Example();
    System.out.println(object.name);
  }
}
```

Here i just printed the Name "Hello World". Now see, its just having alomost 10 lines na ? instead of finishing this work like this, why we are creating POJO Classes and XML file and adding libraries and doing so so . .

really i don't know what we have done with spring ?
Just we are not using the keyword 'new' . thats it . .

Really i'm confused, please help me someone . .  first of all i'm sorry to ask this silly question, but with this doubt i can't move further na, . .

Thank You :)

Comment: google "dependency injection" and "seperation of concerns"

Comment: I think this will explain a bit good http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl

Comment: It is generally not recommended to use Spring for smaller projects, where the benefits of inversion of control and dependency injection outweigh the "cost" of using Spring. Your displayed sample application would also be classified as a "smaller project".

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92393/what-does-the-spring-framework-do-should-i-use-it-why-or-why-not

Comment: The real world applications are not hello world application. They are very complex and involves hundreds of objects and their complexities. Spring is a framework that does many tasks for you, such as dependency injection, AOP etc. Go thru the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610597/why-spring-framework

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at these tutorials ( videos ) https://www.udemy.com/javaspring/?couponCode=copface#/ .first 9 or so are free and will give you a nice understanding of what Spring is all about

Comment: Ya Good . .  so while using a broad size of project with hundreds of objects, we can simply use that from that xml configuration files na ? if it is means i accept this reason. .  Good :)

Comment: As a note, XML configuration is old-style, and Spring Boot handles most of the boilerplate for many kinds of applications.

Comment: You keep asking for the perfect reason to use Spring, and you have three answers telling you that it's a framework for dependency injection, AOP, and utilities, and it shines in large projects. There's no reason you *have* to use Spring in the same way that there's no reason you *have* to use Java or you *have* to drive a car.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework and other similar projects are used to organize large projects and when used correctly can vastly simplify the architecture and reduce the co-dependency of objects within those large projects.

They are generally only useful for large projects or web projects though, the gains you will get from them really don't start to kick in until you start doing more complex things.

Comment: Ya you are correct, that in big project the spring will be useful, but i just wanna the perfect reason simply, i means i need the perfect example, if you can means just say one real time example or anyother relating to this please !

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons (I think the most worthwhile) to use Spring IoC is ability for agile class implementation management.

E.g. you need to change implementation of some class to another one - in case if you're using Spring IoC you need to perform only one thing - to change implementation class name in `.xml` configuration file, you don't need to recompile whole project.

This is advantage of using IoC container - part of rensponsibilities is carried over to external class implementation provider and makes manipulations on whole system more flexible.

I can suggest you to read this great article to get more about IoC containers: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: So, if we need to add something new or removing, we can simply remove the particular fields in xml and there is no need to change in main class right ?

Comment: @RajeevUlaganathan, yes, we make parts of application more independent and exclude hardcoding specific class implementations

Comment: If you're using the modern declarative features like component scanning, you don't even have to change any XML.

Comment: Note that if you're configuring application via annotations you need to recompile classes after any change in annotation value

Comment: Can anyone say one scenario or a situation, there we must use the spring concept, else we can't solve that problem . .  Can you get what i'm asking . . ?

Comment: There's no reason you *have* to use Spring. You could also write your Web application in assembly language.

Comment: Spring IoC is not dedicated to solve specific problems like no one can solve them, but it can make your live mich more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Spring won't be usefull for very small application like your "hello world".

But if you want to developp a more complexe application like a web app, Spring can be usefull.

It is basicly a **container of beans** (*mostly singleton*) created from xml (or java) conf  and/or java annotation and stored in a ApplicationContext. All those beans will be available for **dependency injection** that will help you to simplify your project's architecture.

Comment: Sorry i just gave example only that helloworld. .  actually i need the perfect reason for why we need to move for spring ?

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of answers specify here, Spring is not for small Hello World type projects, but for enterprise level solutions where you want to have a framework handle flow of control and instead focus on what the program needs to do.

With Spring, once you set up your configuration files and so on, handling flow control becomes easy with RequestMappers. You can specify different entry points (handler methods) for GET, POST, DELETE methods for the same URL for example. In additon, you can access form variables easily using annotated params in these methods. In addition you get validation methods for these form objects which you can extend based on your needs. You can easily get properties from files. You can have singleton (or non singleton) classes instantiated during startup. There are several magical things you can do.

But this is only Spring MVC stuff. If you want to add security around your site, you can integrate Spring security. If you want to access the DB, you can use Spring JDBC. I have used ehCaching with Spring. There are several other libraries that integrate nicely with Spring.

But as to your question if you should learn Spring or not, the answer there lies in respect to other params as well. Spring is certainly not the only framework you have at your disposal. There are several competing frameworks like Java EE, for example. In the end, the framework you should use depends on other factors like your requirements and in house competency.